# Jenkins run job in local docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I have a Jenkins where I want to run a job in a remote machine using a docker image that I already have on that machine since my cluster does not have any internet access.

I have seen Jenkins docker plugin, but it seems it´s using a docker repository to get the images.

My question is, which is the best Jenkins plugin to acomplish this?. Run a Jenkins job in a docker container using an image in the machine where the job is running?

Regards.

Comment: did you find an answer